# Replace Special Chars at Attr Level

Tags: vba, ms-access

My app receives third party data.

How can I replace special characters at the column level?

I am mostly concerned about (') and (") (Char 34 & Char 39), but would like to handle anything outside the normal a-z, A-Z, 0-9 character sets.

There are 6-10 attrs for which I would apply this type of replace().

Simplest form:

```
Public Function new_RemoveSpecialChars(strAttr) As String

Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "UPDATE MatchedTb " & _
    "SET MatchedTb." & strAttr & " = Replace(Nz([" & strAttr & "]),Chr(39),Chr(39) & Chr(39));"
db.Execute strSQL

End Function
```

Can I concatenate many compare/replace strings?

Is there a better, more efficient approach?

Comment: If you want to handle all characters except a specific set, I suggest using a UDF and `DoCmd.RunSQL`. However, I'm a bit unclear on exactly what you want.

Comment: My first objective is to properly handle (escape) the ('), (") characters.  Once in place, I think I could replace any remaining non-desired characters (i.e., !@#%^&*, etc.) with a NULL character - but this 2nd step is less problematic for me at the moment.

Comment: Well, for that, I can't see exactly what's wrong with your current approach.

Comment: Thx Eric, I guess this approach seemed a bit brute force, but it may just do the job.  I the past I played with a RegExReplace function, but not sure I want to go that path.

Comment: You may want to include a `WHERE` statement using `InStr()` to check for the presence of the characters to be replaced.

Comment: Options are embedded parameters or open recordset object to loop records and use Edit and Update methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the data a external file? (say csv, xml etc).

I  would pre-process the file BEFORE you import the data. And  you can well do that pre-processing the data from Access. So, I recommend you open the data file - process the data, save the file. You THEN import the file.

#Edit
Since you have to process the data after import?

I recommend you process the data like this:

```
Dim sFields    As String
Dim sField     As Variant
Dim rstData    As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql     As String

sFields = "City,Address,CompanyName"
sField = Split(sFields, ",")
Dim sF         As Variant

Dim strFromChar   As String
strFromChar = Chr(40)
Dim strToChar     As String
strToChar = Chr(39)

strSql = "select * from MatchedTb"

Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)

Do While rstData.EOF = False

  rstData.Edit
  For Each sF In sField
     If Nz(rstData(sF), "") <> "" Then
        rstData(sF) = Replace(rstData(sF), strFromChar, strToChar)
     End If
  Next sF
  rstData.Update
  rstData.MoveNext
Loop

rstData.Close
```

So using a  recordset will eliminate the need to concatenate strings, and also allows you to skip/test for a null and not process.

Comment: No option to pre-process; its not my data until it gets into my DB app.  It is coming off a SQL server.

Comment: Thx Albert, very interesting.  So, step thru each record in the recordset?  20K+ records are common, which is why I was attempting to update column-wise.  Not possible or just not advisable to do by column?

Comment: Albert, your code snippet works exactly as expected.  Thx.  I will need to adapt just a bit, but this is a good start.  - Thank you

Comment: You could also do the for each trick with  "list" of char() separated by comma to have multiple char() replacements i that loop. So inside of for each field, you could have a similar "for each" to have a set of  multiple chars() to replace.  A recordset makes sense here since you don't mess with messy concentatation.  And I suppose you could break out the one replace routine similar to what you original had. But the takeaway here is that you can add a multiple char replace loop inside of the field replace code.

Comment: And yes, performance should be ok. You not see a great or much difference in code, but messy concatenation strings are hard to work with.  So, this is easer to work with, and as noted can be easily extended for a multiple char loop. Just use the same idea as the multiple fields, but now use a list of chars() separated by comma, and then a for each loop. The recordset is also an advantage since you  can execute multiple char replaces and only one update occurs for all the changes.

Comment: Albert, I ran your function against 19K records and 6 attributes, ~50K replacements.  Completed in ~1 sec.  Fantastic!